# Am I doing right?

Tags: halal-haram, doubts

Aoa 
Prophet Ayub As Is called Prophet Job pbuh will a word job considered holy like im doing this job is this word holy.
similarly i consider a word personalize holy as it contain 3 words ali and AL ALI is ASMA UL HUSNA. Is it ocd or i am doing right
if its written on paper should we respect it

Comment: Reposting the same question for example is wrong.

Comment: brother medi1saif i couldnot understand your previous answer please explain

Answer (score 1):

Ayub أيوب is an Arabic synonym of a Hebrew or Aramaic name  I'm not familiar with the original name (nor language) be it Yob or Job er whatever this name in all cases was transliterated so concluding from it to English is simply wrong.

Most names have only a meaning in their original language.
Furthermore there's no backup for interpreting something to any name as they are human made and human choices in most cases.

And there's no relation between the name 'Ali علي and the name or attribute of Allah al-' Aly العلي as the main difference is that the name shows the uniquenrss of this attribute to Allah. As the attribute or adjective علي  or عالي in Arabic refers to high when we create a name out of it it will refer to

> the highest al-' Aly العلي

And no believing Muslim would call himself al-' Aly as it means the (unique) highest which is Allah.

So don't make wrong assumptions and conclusions learn your basics first ask second and learn more.

Comment: so it meams a have waswasa problem

Comment: @123abcghi no it means you make wrong interpretations and conclusions without having knowledge on a matter. Waswasa is related to actions here you shared your thoughts and how you came to these conclusions I don't see waswasa here because they have a certain (wrong) logic. An example of waswasa is when you repeat your wudu' because you doubt having made it right. Also waswasa is often due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: so conclusion is iam wrong in both matters

Comment: im wrong in these both ????

Comment: @123abcghi yes to some extent: your conclusions are wrong. But for example doing a good and correct job is something we are asked to do as Muslims. Respecting Allah's names and attributes certainly is not bad nor wrong.